# Verify OCR in PDF using iText

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, ocr, hebrew

There is a large library of Hebrew books scanned with OCR into text at HebrewBooks.com. I would like to write a utility that will allow me to go through every character in the PDF file and see the character image at the same time as the character that the OCR extracted so that I can correct it if it is wrong.

I am presently using iText. How can I display the image of the character and write the text underneath for editing?

To clarify, I am not trying to use iText for OCR. *I* will be the one doing OCR with my finely tuned reading skills. What I want is to make it easier for me to check the image of the letter against the character chosen by the OCR. I want to simultaneously display the character embedded in the PDF and the image of the page from where the character was extracted.

Comment: OCR is an imperfect science.  That said, iText is not designed to do OCR.  What you're asking for would require an OCR library, or an API that you could integrate with in your current OCR library.